# c# Use EFcore 7 dbcontext to update or insert data in a concurrency program

Tags: c#, concurrency, entity-framework-core, azure-eventhub

I have an application that needs to read events from `AzureEventHub` using the `EventProcessorClient` and write them to `SqlServer`. For the uninitiated, the `EventProcessorClient` opens background tasks when it receives events and passes them to its `Handler`, so I have concurrent tasks. I wrote the following code:

```
public class LogProcessorBackgroundService : BackgroundService
{
     // Omit configuration and initialization of objects

    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, KeyValuePair<DateTime, ClientEvent>> _clientEvents = new();
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, int> _eventsPerPartition = new();

    private readonly ILogger<LogProcessorBackgroundService> _logger;
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public LogProcessorBackgroundService(ILogger<LogProcessorBackgroundService> logger,
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        Guard.Against.Null(logger);
        Guard.Against.Null(serviceProvider);

        _logger = logger;
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        try
        {
            var storageClient = new BlobContainerClient(StorageConnectionString, BlobContainerName);

            var processor = new EventProcessorClient(
                storageClient, ConsumerGroup, EventHubConnectionString, EventProcessorClientOptions);

            processor.ProcessEventAsync += OnProcessEvent;
            processor.ProcessErrorAsync += OnProcessError;

            await processor.StartProcessingAsync(stoppingToken);
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException e)
        {
            _logger.LogError(e.Demystify(), "Task was canceled");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.LogError(e.Demystify(), "An unhandled exception has occurred");
        }
    }

    private Task OnProcessError(ProcessErrorEventArgs errorEventArgs)
    {
        _logger.LogError(errorEventArgs.Exception, "OnProcess error");

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task OnProcessEvent(ProcessEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        try
        {
            if (eventArgs.Data?.EventBody is null ||
                eventArgs.Data.EventBody.ToString().Contains(Constants.EventType.Failure))
                return;
            
            var logAudit = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<LogAuditRoot>(eventArgs.Data.EventBody.ToString(),
                SerializerOptions);

            var clientEvent = logAudit.ClientEvent;


            //i try to retrieve the value of the event with the key, 
            //if the current event is newer than the one inserted previously, 
            //i remove the old one and after that i insert the current one
            if (_clientEvents.TryGetValue(clientEvent.ClientId, out var item))
            {
                if (item.Key > clientEvent.TimeStamp)
                    return;

                _clientEvents.Remove(clientEvent.ClientId, out _);
            }

            if(clientEvent.ClientId != Guid.Empty || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(clientEvent.ClientName))
            {
                _clientEvents.TryAdd(clientEvent.ClientId,
                new KeyValuePair<DateTime, ClientEvent>(clientEvent.TimeStamp, clientEvent));
            }
            
            var partitionId = eventArgs.Partition.PartitionId;
           
            // Initialize or increment the count for the current partition. 
            if (!_eventsPerPartition.TryAdd(partitionId, 0))
            {
                ++_eventsPerPartition[partitionId];
            }

            //if the events are greater than 100 I go to update or insert the db, 
            //and I clean the ConcurrentDIctionary and I go to reset the counter 
            //of the partitions in the other ConcurrentDictionary that I need to do the checkpointing
            if (_eventsPerPartition[partitionId] >= 100)
            {
                await eventArgs.UpdateCheckpointAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                await UpsertDataOnDatabase();
                
                _clientEvents.Clear();
                _eventsPerPartition[partitionId] = 0;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.LogError(e, "ProcessEventHandler exception");
        }
    }

    private async Task UpsertDataOnDatabase()
    {
        using var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();

        var repository = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IRepository>();

        _logger.LogInformation("Count: {Count}", _clientEvents.Count.ToString());

        foreach (var keyValuePair in _clientEvents)
        {
            var activity = await repository.GetAsync<ClientActivity>(keyValuePair.Key);

            if (activity == null)
            {
                activity = keyValuePair.Value.Value.ToEntity();

                repository.Insert(activity);
            }
            else
            {
                activity.ActivityId = keyValuePair.Value.Value.ActivityId;
                activity.TimeStamp = keyValuePair.Value.Value.TimeStamp;
            }
        }

        await repository.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

The problem is that at some point I start getting exceptions when I call the `SaveChangesAsync()` of the type:

> An exception occurred in the database while saving changes for context type 'TeamSystem.IT.IAM.EventHubLogProcessor.Data.DataContext'.
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
> ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_ClientsActivities'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.ClientsActivities'. The duplicate key value is (0664d2f2-c672-4f26-a8a
> 6-4f63c1f053d9).

Because using the `dbcontext` in multiple concurrent tasks maybe while one is trying to do the insert, this thing has already been done in another task and therefore the system can't work. How can I fix this?
Is there any example guide that could help me figure out how to fix this?
I've never worked in applications of this type, so I really don't know where to start.
Thank you in advance for any replies.
Regards.

Comment: I have a question about your problem: when the SqlExcepion is thrown, because of the violation of PRIMARY KEY, what would you want to do with that item? You want to discard it, since it's been already inserted on the database, or you want to add it with a new primary key?
By the way, I think you'd solve the problem by handling the exception properly.

Comment: Hi, if it is already inserted I should actually understand if the record you are trying to insert is more recent or not than the one on the db and if so update or discard it. So only solution to handle the exception?

Comment: You need to use real upsert, that is - atomic one. EF doesn't provide the way to do this, so you may have to switch to raw sql. Alternatively - you can catch pk violation exception and in this case retry the operation. Or use locks in .NET code. There are other options as well.

Comment: Since there's no standard recipe for dealing with concurrency, IMO this is an opinion-based question.

Answer (score -1):

You need to ensure that your `await repository.SaveChangesAsync();` is not called by another thread while it is being executed by another. You can't use `lock` for asynchronous functions so your best bet is using a `Semaphore`.

Something along the lines of:

```
static SemaphoreSlim semaphoreSlim = new SemaphoreSlim(1,1);
...
await semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync();

try
{
    await repository.SaveChangesAsync();
}
finally
{
    semaphoreSlim.Release();
}
```

You can read [this article](https://blog.cdemi.io/async-waiting-inside-c-sharp-locks/) for more details.

Comment: This is a very bad solution. Just think of an application with hundreds of users doing totally different things, or one SaveChanges call that takes 20 minutes (or longer).